# Several UIAlertView in one view: how to create different delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multiple UIAlertView issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084393/multiple-uialertview-issue)

I`am beginner ios developer. And I faced with the following problem:

In my app has one viewController with 2 UIAlertView`s. One of them has UIdatePicker, and the other has UIPickerView. In other words - they are different, with different components and various processing algorithms.

And they must has different handlers. But I don`t know, how create different handlers with "delegate:self" on one viewController.

I do so:

```
-(IBAction)alertDataPicker:(id)sender
{
    selectPickerController *dataPicker=[[selectPickerController alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Отмена" otherButtonTitles:@"Сохранить", nil];
    NSError *err;
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Authors"];
    dataPicker.data = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&err];
    [dataPicker show];

}

-(IBAction)alertDatePicker:(id)sender
{
    datePickerALertControllerViewController *pickerAlertView = [[datePickerALertControllerViewController alloc] initWithTitle:@" " message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Отмена" otherButtonTitles:@"Сохранить", nil];
    pickerAlertView.datePickerView.date=[self stringToDate:createDate.text];
    [pickerAlertView show];
}

#pragma mark UIAlertViewDelegate 
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"qwe");
    //NSLog(@"%@",alertView.datePickerView.date);
    //createDate.text =[self dateToString:alertView.datePickerView.date];
    //NSLog(@"date %@...%@",date,alertView.datePickerView.date);
}
```

But xCode says that UIAlertView don`t has prorepty "datePickerView"
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
But if specify the class object that comes, then a similar problem arises with the properties of an object from another class.

How I can create a different handlers to my UIAlertView`s or can determine which class of object called this method, and depending on it to go to different algorithms?

Thanks in advance for the help and for your advice.

Comment: FYI: [The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `tag`s to each `UIAlertView` to distinguish them when the delegate methods are called. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819267/show-alert-in-clickedbuttonatindex/4819371#4819371).

Another way would be checking if the delegate's `alertView` is equal to one of your `UIAlertView`controls:

```
if ([alertView isEqual:myAlertView]) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, both of which solutions are very simple and seemingly obvious. All genius is simple))